# Visual Studio 2012 Dark Theme Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2012, themes

I've been using the Visual Studio's Dark Theme for a while now. But as of today it got messed up. I'm not sure what triggered it but I'm speculating that opening an MVC3 project corrupted something. Please see the current behavior below.

[image: Dark Theme issue]

How do I get this fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

The issue is that the "Item foreground" and "Item background" settings gets set to something OTHER than "Default".

**The fix** is to go to Tools > Options > Environment - Fonts and Colors and setting the said properties to "Default".

[image]

---

Well, I fiddled with the Tools > Options > Environment - Fonts and Colors options for a while and managed to restore order. I'm not sure what messed it up initially!

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of issues with the dark theme in VS2012. In order to make it work again I go to Tools -> Options -> Visual Experience and switch it to a different theme and then apply the dark theme again.